# Get possible ranges of int collection

Tags: c#, linq, int, range

I have a List of id's (`int`) like

```
[1,2,3,5,7,8,11,13,14..]
```

is there a fast/smart way (linq?) to get all id's or if possible, the ranges?
The result should be like `[1-3, 5, 7-8, 11, 13-14]`.

Sure, it's easy to loop and count the int value to get the result but I'm sure there must be a easier way to do this.

Comment: what is the logic to generate range? why not 1-5, 3-8 etc?

Comment: _is there a fast/smart way (linq?)_ - if by "fast" you mean execution speed, then "foreach" will be always faster then LINQ

Answer (score 1):

**disclaimer** *this is very slow on big list, you should do a distinct too*

this should do the trick

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //a list with a possible of duplicate
        var theList = (new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14, 13 }).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

        var step1 = theList.Select((a, b) =>  theList.Skip(b).TakeWhile((x, y) => a == x || theList[b + y] - 1 == theList[b + y - 1]));

        var step2 = step1.GroupBy(x => x.Last())
                         .Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y).Distinct())
                         .Select(x => x.Count() > 1 ? string.Format("{0}-{1}", x.First(), x.Last()) : x.First().ToString());


        var result = string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", step2));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school way with a single for loop.

```
try
{
     List<int> i = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14 };
     int istart = i[0];
     bool flag = false;
     // Use StringBuilder
     for(int index = 0;index<i.Count-1;index++)
     {
         if ((i[index] + 1) == i[index + 1])
         {
              flag = true;
              continue;
         }
         else
         {
              if (!flag)
                  Console.Write(istart);
              else
                  Console.Write(istart + "-" + i[index]);

              Console.Write(",");

              flag = false;
              istart = i[index + 1];
          }
      }
      if (istart + 1 == i[i.Count - 1])
          Console.Write(istart + "-" + i[i.Count - 1]);
      else
          Console.WriteLine(istart);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.Read();
```

Input `List<int> i = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14 };`

[image]

Input `List<int> i = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 13, 13 };`

[image]

Input `List<int> i = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 13, 15, 17 };`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a linq way to do it (if numbers do not repeat), but I am not sure if it is easier:

```
int last = -1;
int rank = 0;
IEnumerable<string> grouped = arr
    .GroupBy(i =>
    {
        rank += i - last - 1;
        last = i;
        return rank;
    })
    .Select(g => g.Count() == 1 ? g.First().ToString()
                : g.First().ToString() + "-" + g.Last().ToString());
```

It seems rather complicated to me, more resource intensive than necessary and not flexible. Linq is great for many cases, but sometimes it just does not fit well. Simple loop is sometimes the best you can get:

```
IEnumerable<string> Group(IEnumerable<int> sortedArr)
{
    using (var en = sortedArr.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!en.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        int first = en.Current;
        int last = first;
        int count = 1;

        while (true)
        {
            bool end;
            if ((end = !en.MoveNext()) || en.Current - last > 1)
            {
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    yield return first.ToString();
                }
                //else if (count == 2)
                //{
                //    yield return first.ToString();
                //    yield return last.ToString();
                //}
                else
                {
                    yield return first.ToString() + "-" + last.ToString();
                }
                if (end) { yield break; }
                first = en.Current;
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ++count;
            }
            last = en.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

**Benchmarks**

Lets measure how (in)efficient the linq actually is here on 10M array:

```
  simple loop:  328MB, 1.2sec
      my linq:  790MB, 2.7sec 
 Fredous linq:  1100MB, 7days (estimated)
```

the code:

```
int size = 10000000;
int[] arr = new int[size];
Random rnd = new Random(1);

arr[0] = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
{
    if (rnd.Next(100) < 25)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 2;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + 1;
    }
}         

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch st = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
st.Start();
var res = Group(arr).ToList();
st.Stop();

MessageBox.Show(st.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(res.Sum(s => s.Length).ToString());// to be sure the work is done
```

Comment: you should put the actual benchmark code in the answer too ;-)

Comment: @Fredou ok, added

Comment: i added a little disclaimer on my answer ;-)

Comment: @Fredou I agree with the first half of the disclaimer, but do not understand the "you should do a distinct too".

Answer (score 0):

Considering a ordered list and unique ids, I think the simplest approach is to use classic *for* and *while*

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14 };
                int i = 0;
                bool isrange;

                for(i=0;i<ids.Count;i++)
                {
                    isrange = false;
                    Console.Write(ids[i]);

                    while (i < ids.Count-1 && ids[i + 1] == ids[i] + 1)
                    {
                        i++;
                        isrange = true;
                    }

                    if (isrange)
                        Console.Write("-" + ids[i]);

                    if (!(i + 1 == ids.Count))
                        Console.Write(",");
                }
```